# sql data to asp:table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datatable

I want that webpage connects to SQL database, and displays selected data in table. I have a query:

```
select top 5 
    r.remoteid, 
    count(distinct m.mac) as mac,  
    count(distinct i.igmp) as igmp, 
    i.date
from 
    remoteid as r
join 
    dbo.mac as m on m.mazgas = r.mazgas and m.portas = r.portas 
join 
    dbo.igmp as i on i.mazgas = m.mazgas and i.portas = m.portas and i.date = m.date
where  
    i.date = DATEADD(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
group by 
    r.remoteid, r.mazgas, r.portas, m.vlan, m.date, i.date
order by 
    igmp desc
```

What is the best way to fill returned values to asp:table in HTML (`<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>`).

The table should look like this:

```
remoteid     date  
 remote    mac|igmp
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Gridview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<asp:Table>` is not a data control. You have to use `<asp:GridView>`.

Comment: I didn't know about '<asp:GridView>'. Now I've made a solution by making datatable and binding data.